# ZF2 share models between modules

Tags: php, class, module, zend-framework2, models

Hi I'm trying to share models between my modules, but when I call my getServiceLocator()->get('Mail\Model\Mail') in my controller from another module the class cannot be found.

I'm searching for a solution for a few days now, but I can't find one thats working for me.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Mail\Model\Mail' => function($sm) {
                $mail = new Mail();
                return $mail;
            },
            'Mail\Model\MailTable' => function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('MailTableGateway');
                $table        = new MailTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'MailTableGateway' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter          = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Mail());
                return new TableGateway('mail', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

When I return a string instead it's working fine so the I know I'm calling the right key, but when I try to return my class it can't be found.

In my mail module the class is working fine.. If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably you have a `use xxx` line for your `Mail` class in your Module.php? What error are you getting? You don't need to do anything special to share models between modules.

Comment: You shouldn't use factories for the classes where you don't inject anything (e.g Mail\Model\Mail). You should use invokables for that. This won't fix your problem though

Comment: I solved the problem! My module had the following structure: "/Project/module/Mail/src/Model" while it should be "/Project/module/Mail/src/Mail/Model".

But thank you for the help!